# How do I execute a "rake task" after every db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm working on a personal project and I have a strange doubt. At the localhost, I do `rake db:reset` almost every time and I always need to run another task named **newsworker:create** (in other words, I run `rake newsworker:create`).

### My questions are:

1. How can I execute a specific rake task after every `rake db:reset`?
2. How can I generalize the above question to work with `rake db:create` and other tasks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way is to create your own rake task calling all the tasks needed (to avoid changing Rails/Rake basic tasks):

```
# lib/tasks/reset_and_create
namespace :database do
  desc 'Reset the database to a fresh and clean DB ready for use'
  task :reset_and_create do
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
    Rake::Task['newsworker:create'].invoke
    # if you need to pass arguments to your tasks, use:
    # Rake::Task['your_task'].invoke(your_arg, another_arg)
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
rake database:reset_and_create
```

Comment: Thanks! But a short question: if I can add tasks to the :database namespace, can I override the default `db:reset` task?

Comment: I think you can but I think you should not do it. I am not sure if you can safely create tasks in the `:db` namespace.

Comment: Okay, I hope someone that have more knowledge can answer this question of my comment. Anyway, thanks for the answer about the official question :)